# Multiple regex in one command

Tags: regex-group, regex-negation

*Disclaimer: I have no engineering background whatsoever - please don't hold it against me ;)*

What I'm trying to do:
Scan a bunch of text strings and find the ones that

- are more than one word
- contain title case (at least one capitalized word after the first one)
- but exclude specific proper nouns that don't get checked for title case
- and disregard any parameters in curly brackets

Example: Today, a Man walked his dogs named {FIDO} and {Fifi} down the Street.
Expectation: Flag the string for title capitalization because of Man and Street, not because of Today, {FIDO} or {Fifi}

Example: Don't post that video on TikTok.
Expectation: No flag because TikTok is a proper noun

I have bits and pieces, none of them error-free from what https://www.regextester.com/ keeps telling me so I'm really hoping for help from this community.

What I've tried (in piece meal but not all together):

- (?=([A-Z][a-z]+\s+[A-Z][a-z]+))
- ^(?!(WordA|WordB)$)
- ^((?!{*}))

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is not really solvable solely with regex...
My recommendation would be splitting the input via `[\s\W]+` (e.g. with python's [re.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split), if you really need strings with more than one word, you can check the length of the result), filtering each resulting word if the first character is uppercase (e.g with python's [string.isupper](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_isupper.asp)) and finally filtering against a dictionary.

`[\s\W]+` matches all whitespace and non-word characters, yielding words...

The reasoning behind this different approach: compiling all "proper nouns" in a regex is kinda impossible, using "isupper" also works with non-latin letters (e.g. when your strings are unicode, `[A-Z]` won't be sufficient to detect uppercase). Filtering utilizing a dictionary is a way more forward approach and much easier to maintain (I would recommend using `set` or other data type suited for fast lookups.

Maybe if you can define your use case more clearer we can work out a pure regex solution...